# Understanding [<-, [[<-, and vec_c for vctrs list_of

Tags: r, vctrs

*Asking question that I asked on the [RStudio community forums](https://community.rstudio.com/t/understanding-and-vec-c-for-vctrs-list-of/47663) in case anyone is able to provide assistance here.*

Hello everyone, I am trying to better understand the behavior of `[<-`, `[[<-`, `vec_c`, and `c` for list_of classes. I am defining a `list_of` subclass that essentially is a list of a character vectors that should be split on spaces. I want to use the assignment operators to adjust values within as necessary, but am struggling to fully understand the `vctrs` implementation. I have provided a reprex below that highlights what I'm trying to figure out.

**Example class**

```
library(vctrs)
library(stringr)

new_example <- function(x = list()) {
  if (vec_is(x, character())) {
    x <- str_split(x, " ")
  }
  new_list_of(x,
              ptype = character(),
              class = "example")
}

vec_ptype_full.example <- function(x, ...) {
  "example"
}

vec_ptype_abbr.example <- function(x, ...) {
  "xmpl"
}
```

**Boiler plate for coercion and casting**

```
vec_ptype2.example <- function(x, y, ...) UseMethod("vec_ptype2.example", y)

vec_ptype2.example.default <- function(x, y, ..., x_arg = "x", y_arg = "y") {
  vec_default_ptype2(x, y, x_arg = x_arg, y_arg = y_arg)
}

vec_cast.example <- function(x, to, ...) UseMethod("vec_cast.example")

vec_cast.example.default <- function(x, to, ...) vec_default_cast(x, to)
```

**Coercion between example and character**

```
vec_ptype2.example.character <- function(x, y, ...) x

vec_ptype2.character.example <- function(x, y, ...) y
```

**Casting between example and character**

```
vec_cast.character.example <- function(x, to, ...) map_chr(x, str_c, collapse = " ")

vec_cast.example.character <- function(x, to, ...) new_example(x)

vec_cast.example.example <- function(x, to, ...) new_example(x)
```

**Testing**

```
a <- new_example("a b")
a
#> <example[1]>
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a" "b"

# Error
a[2] <- "c d"
#> Error: Can't cast `x` <list_of<character>> to `to` <example>.

# String not split
a[[2]] <- "e f"
a
#> <example[2]>
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "e f"

# String is split
a[[2]] <- c("e", "f")
a
#> <example[2]>
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "e" "f"

# String is split
vec_c(a, "g h")
#> <example[3]>
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "e" "f"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "g" "h"
c(a, "g h")
#> <example[3]>
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "e" "f"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "g" "h"
```

In order to assign values to existing rows, is there a way to use either `[<-` or `[[<-` to assign a full string such as `"d e"` and be split, or is the best option to use `[[<-` with a character vector that is already split such as `c("d", "e")`?

The crux of the question is, using `vec_c` and `c`, the new value seems to be passed through `new_example`, and thus the string is split. `[[<-` seems to avoid this, and `[<-` converts the string to a `list_of` class before sending to the constructor function, but I'm still hazy on how I could adjust these details to work in this use case (and just better understand how `vctrs` is supposed to work).